# How to fix ethtool not showing enough output

Tags: networking

I was trying to setup Wake-on-LAN. The tutorial I used stated to use ethtool to change wol settings. However when I ran the following command:

```
# ethtool wlp5s0
```

Output:

```
Link Detected: yes
```

I am used to more verbose output:

```
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: d
Wake-on: d
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
Link detected: yes
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ip link enable wlp5s0
```

I think your wlan interface is off try doing `ip link`